# Positive connotation of 'upshot"?

Tags: meaning

Upshot, as defined, is only a result, good or bad. However, I seem to have heard it only in connection with a positive outcome. Is this true? Does "upshot" have a positive connotation attached?

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/96200/whats-the-upshot